# How can I assign a class instance by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, class, reference, sdl

I've written an SDL graphics program in C++ (it's about 300 lines, so I will try to summarize). The program involves Springs and Vertices, both of which are classes. [Springs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) apply a force to its two [Vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle#Point_mass) in a Hookean fashion.

Here is the code initializing three vertices, and two springs. `S1` and `S2` are springs, and `V1`, `V2` and `V3` are vertices.

```
    //Initialize vertices
    Vertex V1;
    V1.pos.x = 100;
    V1.pos.y = 300;

    Vertex V2;
    V2.pos.x = 200;
    V2.pos.y = 200;

    Vertex V3;
    V3.pos.x = 300;
    V3.pos.y = 100;

    //Initialize springs
    Spring S1;
    S1.p0 = V1;
    S1.p1 = V2;

    Spring S2;
    S2.p0 = V2;
    S2.p1 = V3;
```

The intention is that `V2` is connected to both `S1` and `S2`, and that the two springs are connected to each other through this vertex. What really happens is that by writing `S2.p0 = V2;`, a copy of V2 is made. I made this illustration to clarify.

[image: An illustration of the intended result]

So here's my question: How can I edit the above code so that I get the intended result? That is, how can I assign `p0` and `p1` to the springs, such that they refer to the original objects? Basically, I'm trying to assign *references* to `V2`, rather than *copies* of `V2`. How would I do this?

Comment: Pointers or reference types, what have you tried.

Comment: Pointers confuse me to no end. I'm not sure whether to simply assign pointers to `V1-3`, or to change something about the definition of `p0` and `p1` in the `Spring` class

Comment: Nicely illustrated question! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your definition of `Spring` to store `Vertex` pointers or references. Pointers will give you more flexibility to do things move a spring and attach to a different vertex:

```
struct Spring {
  Vertex* p0;
  Vertex* p1;
};
```

And then set them like this:

```
Spring S1;
S1.p0 = &V1;
S1.p1 = &V2;
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked for me. After making this change, I still had to edit each use of `p0.member` and `p1.member` in the Spring class to `p0->member` and `p1->member`.

Comment: Yes, any time you want to use `p0` or `p1` you will need to dereference the pointers. Beware of uninitialized, null or dangling pointers. You might want the constructor of `Spring` to initialize `p0` and `p1` to `nullptr` and then check for `nullptr` before you dereference. You will encounter dangling pointers if you try and use a spring after the vertices it is attached to have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your class Spring stores a Vertex like in

```
class Spring {
public:
    Vertex p0, p1;
}
```

but you want Spring to store a reference to a Vertex like in

```
class Spring {
public:
    Vertex &p0, &p1;
}
```

Using references as class members implies that Spring needs a constructor to initialize p0 and p1:

```
Spring(Vertex &v1, Vertex &v2) : p0(v0), p1(v1) {}
```

And you need to rewrite your Spring creation to

```
Spring S1(V1, V2);
```

You need to make sure that V1 lives at least as long as S1 so that the reference stays valid.

Of course Spring can also store pointers to Vertex instead if references. Pointers could be changed later, whereas the references can only be set during construction.

Comment: I would prefer pointers so you can reuse your spring with different vertex later.